# How To Switch Focus To A Different Tab Using DevExpress' DockPanel and DocumentManager

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a DocumentManager **DocumentManager1** (onto which I have placed one dock panel **dockPanel1** in the WinForms designer. I docked the **dockPanel1** so that it is docked full. It looks like a tab with the caption "Empty".

I have another dock panel **dockPanel2** that I add programmatically:

```
dockPanelCaption = "New";

var dockPanel2 = new DockPanel
{
   Text = dockPanelCaption,
   Name = dockPanelCaption,
   Tag = dockPanelCaption,         
};

documentManager1.View.AddDocument(dockPanel2);
```

This produces a GUI that looks like this (I circled the New dock panel I added using the code above):

[image]

All I want to  do is *programatically* switch focus to the New "tab" (i.e., dock panel). I feel silly to admit that I have invested hours trying to do this--first experimenting on my own and then by scouring DevExpress articles. Here what doesn't work:

- dockPanel2.Focus();
- documentManager1.View.ActivateDocument(dockPanel2);

I've also experimented with the **TabbedView** object, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
documentManager1.View.Controller.ActivateDocument(dockPanel2);
```

or:

```
documentManager1.ActivePanel = dockPanel2;
```

Comment: I have been away from the code and will be away on travel. But I will verify your answer and post again soon. Thanks.